# Grub escape when trying to boot windows

Tags: windows, grub, operating-systems, manjaro

Hi i was dual booting manjaro + windows10 and made a mistake when deleting manjaro partion and am now getting grub rescue when trying to start my computer. Ive tried various tutorials/methods but i cant seem to get it working. I downloaded an iso file for windows 10 and burnt it into a usb, but i cant seem to get my lenevo laptop to boot from that USB directly, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit your question to provide a photo of the Grub rescue screen and any other details that might be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Knoppix bootable ISO file from https://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html
2. Burn Knoppix ISO to CD or DVD or install the .ISO to a bootable USB flash drive.
3. Boot to Knoppix from that removable media.
4. Use Knoppix's mount of NTFS to edit your Grub configuration file that exists in Windows.  Save the edits.
5. Use Knoppix's mount of any remaining Manjaro filesystems (e.g., other partitions or mass storage devices than the Manjaro partition that you deleted) to back up any files created or modified in prior Manjaro boot ups.  (This is your final chance to back up those files.)
6. Try to use Knoppix's GPartEd to see whether you can revive the Manjaro partition in situ as nondestructively as possible to bring it back as it was without reformatting that partition.
7. Remove the removable media, so as to boot to Windows like normal (or to Manjaro if the GPartEd in situ revival of the Manjaro partition without reformatting was successful).
8. Reinstall Manjaro Linux on the correct partition if the GPartEd step above wasn't successful.